# problems with webpage layout

Tags: html, css

I have this page

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pagina</title>
        <link href="estilo_duda.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="contenedor">
            <div id="encabezado">
                Encabezado
            </div>
            <div id="menu">
                Menu con las opciones
            </div>

            <div id="principal">
            Principal
            Principal
            Principal
            </div>
            <div id="publicidad">
            Publicidad
            </div>          

            <div id="piedepagina">
            Pie de Pagina
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

this css

```
.contenedor
{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#encabezado
{
    font-family: Garamond,Arial;
    font-size: 40px; 
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25px;  
    color: white;
    width: 987px; /* Ancho */
    height: 100px; /* Alto */
    background-color: #000000;
}

#menu
{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 40px;    
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: white;
    width: 200px; /* Ancho */
    height: 1720px; /* Alto */
    float: left;    
}

#principal
{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 650px; /* Ancho */
    height: 1720px; /* Alto */  
    color: #3FC665;
    float: left;  
    padding-left: 10px;
}

#publicidad
{
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 127px; /* Ancho */
    height: 1720px; /* Alto */
    text-align: center;     
    color: yellow;
    float: left;        
}

#piedepagina
{
    font-family: Garamond;
    font-size: 20px; 
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: orange;  
    width: 987px;  /* Ancho */
    height: 50px;  /* Alto */
    background-color: #000000;
    padding-top: 25px;  
    clear:both;     
}
```

on my 14 inch monitor but it looks good widescreen monitor looks bad, because it appears all right aligned content

[image]

anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Do you mean left aligned?

Comment: @user1851950 Your question isn't understandable, please tell us what the problem really is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the following code in your CSS File & include the break tag in your HTML File (Menu).

```
body {
background-color:#000000;
font-family: georgia,sans-serif;
color:#333;
margin:0;
padding:0; 
}

.contenedor
{
width: 1100px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#encabezado
{
font-family: Garamond,Arial;
font-size: 40px; 
text-align: center;
padding-top: 25px;  
color: white;
width: 987px; 
height: 100px; 
background-color: #000000;
}

#menu
{
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 30px;    
text-align: center;
background-color: #000000;
color: white;
width: 130px; 
height: 500px; 
float: left;    
}

#principal
{
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 20px;
background-color: #000000;
width: 750px; 
height: 500px;   
color: #3FC665;
float: left;  
padding-left: 100px;
}

#publicidad
{
font-family: Arial;
background-color: #000000;
width: 100px; 
height: 500px; 
text-align: center;     
color: yellow;
float: left;        
}

#piedepagina
{
font-family: Garamond;
font-size: 20px; 
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
color: orange;  
width: 987px;  
height: 50px;  
background-color: #000000;
padding-top: 25px;  
clear:both;   
}
```

Result :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your width is set incorrectly. Setting the width of 'contenedor' to auto makes it fill the whole screen, but your actual content is set to 987px, but its inside 'contenedor'.

You could set the width of 'contenador' to 987px, that would center the content.

Answer (score 0):

This CSS will center the content in the browser window and apply the black background to the whole page, not just the section with content:

```
body {
    background-color: #000000;
}

.contenedor
{
    width: 987px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#encabezado
{
    font-family: Garamond,Arial;
    font-size: 40px; 
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25px;  
    color: white;
    width: 987px; /* Ancho */
    height: 100px; /* Alto */
}

#menu
{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 40px;    
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    width: 200px; /* Ancho */
    height: 1720px; /* Alto */
    float: left;    
}

#principal
{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 650px; /* Ancho */
    height: 1720px; /* Alto */  
    color: #3FC665;
    float: left;  
    padding-left: 10px;
}

#publicidad
{
    font-family: Arial;
    width: 127px; /* Ancho */
    height: 1720px; /* Alto */
    text-align: center;     
    color: yellow;
    float: left;        
}

#piedepagina
{
    font-family: Garamond;
    font-size: 20px; 
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: orange;  
    width: 987px;  /* Ancho */
    height: 50px;  /* Alto */
    padding-top: 25px;  
    clear:both;     
}
```

That said, your CSS could be reduced even further. You shouldn't need to specify the height of items - the content can typically just naturally fill that out on its own. You may want to look into a grid-based layout.